# Proguard сохраняет возвращаемое значение функции

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, proguard

Я сделал функцию которая запрашивает актуальную версиюю из сети, но после подключения Proguard функция стала возвращать только ту версию, которая была на момент сборки приложения. Я пытался редактировать proguard-rules.pro, но безуспешно. Знаете ли вы в чем может быть проблема, и как её исправить? Вот сама функция:

```
fun getVersion() {
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://.../version.txt")
        .build()

    return client.newCall(request).execute().body?.string()
}
```

P.S Я немного изменил ThreadPolicy чтобы можно было запустить в UI Thread.

```
val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
```

Comment: При чём тут proguard если версия берётся из сети, не прописана в коде, не хранится в ресурсах - обфускатор вообще никак не может знать текущую версию, чтобы её заинлайнить. Скорее проблема в кешировании запроса. Попробуйте грохнуть данные/кеш приложения и после проверить версию ещё раз - если изменится, то это точно кеширование.

Comment: Пробовал уже, не помогло. Подозрения упали на proguard потому что именно после его включения появилась эта проблема.